# Is it possible to add html to a component call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to add html to a component call?

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText="<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>"
>
```

I have tried a few different methods to show `<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>` as an icon. Is this possible in the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you receive this string as HTML, say from an API call or a third party service, you can render it in client only using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). This process might look something like this:

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText='<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>'
>
```

In the component

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: expandText }} />
```

However, if you are creating the string on your own, then you are better off rendering it as JSX.

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText={<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>}
>
```

Here, you are essentially passing a ReactNode that React can render inside the component.

```
function ExpandCollapse({ expandText }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {expandText}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that is because you are passing a string in the `expandText` attribute whereas you should be passing a a react component.
Create a react functional component with the `<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>` as return value and change the code to

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText={<NewComponent />}
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it as jsx not as a string

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText={<span className="fal fa-arrow-down"></span>}
>
```

Or something like

```
<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  // This is an anti pattern though - Creates new component inside of render fn.
  expandText={() => <span className="fal fa-arrow-down" />}
>
```

Or Extract it out as a componentsomething like,

```
const Icon = () => <span className="fal fa-arrow-down" />

<ExpandCollapse
  previewHeight="250px"
  expandText={Icon} // But this depends on how you render it in ExpandCollapse
  expandText={<Icon />} // Or this..
>
```